# When styling in react native flex=1 not working

Tags: react-native

Hello i am fairly new to React Native and am using flex=1 for making a button cover the entire width of the screen but that is not happening for some reason.

[The script for creating the button component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Olusx.png)

[The result in the emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScGgd.png)

[Using the button component to create a button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtlKy.png)

Answer (score 5):

-Flex:1 cover the entire width and height of its container.

-In your case your view (line 9) is taking the whole space available of its container
which is the TouchableOpacity (line 8)

The problem is that the TouchableOpacity doesn't take the whole space available because you didn't give it that instruction.

> Just add style={{flex:1}} to your TouchableOpacity and it should work

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TouchableOpacity` as a View, so you can remove the inner `<View>...</View>` component from your `Button` and use only `<TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonStyle}><Text style={styles.textStyling}>Buy now</Text></TouchableOpacity>`.

I don't know how is your `CardSection` component, but I can bet that setting `flex: 1` to `TouchableOpacity` and removing nested View will solve your problem,.

You're using the style sheet in a wrong way. The correct way is to import `StyleSheet` from `react-native`, as follows:

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  buttonStyle: {
    backgroundColor: "#f7f7f7",
    flex: 1, // This will be applied to TouchableOpacity
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },
  textStyling: {
     // ...
  }
});
```

I strong recommend you to take a look at [Native Base](http://nativebase.io) (it's a set of components ready to use).

You can try this solution online accessing this [snack](https://snack.expo.io/Hk2_UTqtQ)

Answer (score 0):

make ---> <View style = {{flex: 1}} >  <----- in your app.js file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).